# Best practice on the use of PHP Class Variable?

Tags: php, class

I know this is a subjective question, but it's been haunting me for years.

Let's jump straight to a simple **Example**:

```php
class MyClass {
  private $username;

  function __constructor( $username ) {
    $this->username = $username;
  }

  function register() {
    if( $this->_has_duplicate( $this->username ) ) { // #1
      return false;
    }

    ...
  }

  private function _has_duplicate( $username ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In #1, I passed on a class variable to `_has_duplicate()`. But that function also has access to the same class variable...

Should I simply pass nothing and call the variable inside `_has_duplicate()`?

Is the code below follow better practice?

```php
...

  function register() {
    // pass nothing
    if( $this->_has_duplicate() ) {
      return false;
    }

    ...
  }

  private function _has_duplicate() {
    // when needed I call $this->username
    ...
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Both are right but my advice is: you should think about SRP where/who username belong and in future testing you can easy test has_duplicate($var) but without parameter you always need test register() or refactor methods. I prefer first approach. No hidden (helper) functionality.

Comment: Please refer this [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected-in-php/]

Comment: @daremachine I see, my first code being easier to test is a convincing reason enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Put this question in _codereview_; you'll get some good answers. Personally, I'd say the 2nd approach is favorable since the function is private and is not accessible from outside the class, you don't need the ability to pass anything to it. As for testing, since this method is private, you're still going to have to create a `MyClass` object which requires a `username` in its constructor and call `register`; your test will look like `$obj = new MyClass('user_name_already_exists'); $this->assertEquals(false, $obj->register());`. If this method was public, then that'd change my opinion.

Comment: @waterloomatt ah that's a very compelling reason never thought about that before. Will try to post in codereview too. Thanks!

Comment: @waterloomatt you are right but from my experience is easy refactor composed logic instead of rewrite encapsulated methods without parameters. Eg. in future you see hi($name)?string can be more easy changed than hi() { ...100 lines }

Comment: I think latter approach is optimized and efficient( saves time and code size ), why have extra step in the making if you can just use the same variable in _has_duplicate() ?